# The Python Ethos

Tags: python

I've read in an *Computer Science edX Course* that you can write `programs` to do the same thing in many ways.

Then I came across two examples of simple `search` procedures:

a 'pythonic' search:

```
   def search(list, element):
        for e in list:
            if e == element: 
                return True
        return False
```

a recursive search:

```
def rSearch(list,element):
    if element == list[0]:
        return True
    if len(list) == 1:
        return False
    return rSearch(list[1:],element)
```

**I ask**: what is the essence of a pythonic code?

Comment: open console and enter `import this`

Comment: Honestly, whatever works and makes you feel like you did a good job.

Comment: An important point for code to be considered "pythonic" is that it used the language features available in Python. Both your example are not pythonic to me since (a) the built-in `list` is shadowed be reusing the name and (b) a simple `element in list` does the job. But there is no defined checklist for pythonic code.

Comment: IMO this question is much too philosophical to be a good for for Stack Overflow.

Comment: P.S. I would consider neither of the two snippets to be particularly Pythonic. For starters, they're: (a) using a built-in identifier for a function argument; (b) doing a very poor job handling corner cases; (c) ignoring existing Python idioms.

Comment: `for` iteration is common in Python.  Recursion is possible, but not regularly used.  Python does not implement tail recursion.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The most Pythonic way would probably be to use the built in `in` statement

```
element in list
```

You could wrap it in a function:

```
def search(list, element):
    return element in list
```

I wouldn't even bother doing that. They made it a statement so you can use it freely, without a thought.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
element = 3
element in list
```

returns

```
True
```

It might help to read *The Zen of Python* to get a feel for what is 'pythonic' and what isn't.

type `import this` into your Python interpreter to read whenever you like, but here it is in full. Notice the bolded line which shows that Python (unlike Perl, Ruby, and your edX book) considers there should really only be one *right* way of doing something.

The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.

Explicit is better than implicit.

Simple is better than complex.

Complex is better than complicated.

Flat is better than nested.

Sparse is better than dense.

Readability counts.

Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

Although practicality beats purity.

Errors should never pass silently.

Unless explicitly silenced.

In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

**There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.**

Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.

Now is better than never.

Although never is often better than *right* now.

If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.

Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!